# Retain multiple fileEntries with chrome filesystem API?

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-chrome-app

How can I retain multiple fileEntry objects to reuse when the user opens the app with the chrome filesystem API? I've tried to use arrays to store the file entries and it works fine up until I restart the app and can't use them. Instead of returning a fileEntry object the console returns an object object (this is after I used `chrome.storage.local.set` and `chrome.storage.local.get` to set and retrieve the entries once the user restarted the app.)

Comment: I find your lack of code disturbing.

Comment: @DanielHerr ? I'm asking for help. I find _your_ lack of code disturbing. I simply need a way to retain and restore _multiple_ file entries using the chrome filesystem API.

Comment: How can you be helped if you do not post what you have?

Comment: @DanielHerr You want me to post code that doesn't work? I'm not asking for a fix to my code, I'm asking how to do it in the first place. So far I've only tried saving an array of fileEntries, but when retrieving the code it just says it's not a fileEntry object.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot persist the actual file entries between sessions. You need to use [chrome.fileSystem.retainEntry](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/fileSystem#method-retainEntry) which will return an id, which you can store, and then use [chrome.fileSystem.restoreEntry](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/fileSystem#method-restoreEntry) to regain access to the entry when the app is re-opened.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of back and forth, I figured out how to retain *multiple* fileEntries.
Here's the code for the people who need it.

```
  //save
  //'fileEntries' is an array that I made earlier where multiple entries were stored
  var keep = [];
  fileEntries.forEach(function(entry, index) {
    //if it's empty or null, return nothing
    //otherwise add the id to our empty array 'keep'
    if (entry == null) {
      //do nothing
    } else {
      keep[index] = chrome.fileSystem.retainEntry(entry);
    }
  });
  chrome.storage.local.set({
    retained: keep
  });
  //load
  chrome.storage.local.get('retained', function(data) {
  var retained = data.retained;
  retained = retained.filter(function(d) {
    return d
  });
  for (var i = 0; i < retained.length; i++) {
    var tab = retained[i];
    chrome.fileSystem.restoreEntry(tab, function(entry) {
      fileEntries.push(entry);
    });
  }
});
```

And.... thats about it! When the loading function is done, the `fileEntries` array, has all the fileEntry objects!